# R: How to fit a time series model such as "Y(t) = αX + βY(t-1)"?

Tags: r, time-series, regression, forecasting, autoregressive-models

How do I fit this model in R, step by step? My scope is to make a forecast for t+1.

### Y(t) = αX(t) + βY(t-1)

- *Y(t) <- years from 1900 to 2000.*
- *X <- a score measure from 0 to 100.*
- *Y(t-1) <- lagged value of order 1 for Y.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a tutorial, just a way of doing it. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is an AR(1) time series for `y` with covariate `x`. We can just use `arima0` (no missing value) or `arima` (missing value allowed) from R base:

```
fit <- arima0(y, order = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = x)
```

Let's consider a small example:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- runif(100)
## intercept: 0.1
## slope of `x`: 1.2
## AR(1) with coefficient 0.5
y <- 0.1 + 1.2 * x + arima.sim(list(ar = 0.5), n = 100, sd = 0.2)

fit <- arima0(y, order = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = x)

#Call:
#arima0(x = y, order = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = x)
#
#Coefficients:
#         ar1  intercept    xreg
#      0.4639     0.0645  1.2139
#s.e.  0.0879     0.0448  0.0590
#
#sigma^2 estimated as 0.03046:  log likelihood = 32.55,  aic = -57.11
```

Note the estimate is consistent with our true model.

---

> Thanks. How do I insert more covariates (x1,x2,etc.), just in case?

Have a look at `?arima0` (or `?arima`):

```
xreg: Optionally, a vector or matrix of external regressors, which
      must have the same number of rows as ‘x’.
```

You can specify a model matrix via `xreg`. Suppose you have regressors `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, in a data frame `dat`, you can generate this model matrix via:

```
X <- model.matrix(~ x1 + x2 + x3, dat)
```

Then

```
fit <- arima0(y, order = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = X)
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I insert more covariates (x1,x2,etc.), just in case?

Comment: just have x as a dataframe with multiple columns for each covariate. The one catch is that if they're factors you're going to have to use a model.matrix to create dummy variables for each level of the factor.

Comment: @Zheyuan Li Thanks. I didn't see your comments when I started writing my post or I wouldn't have written it. It was strange having nearly identical answers and being ignored though. Thought my posts weren't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Use the forecast package and use an ARIMAX function and specify the structure, it will be (1,0,0) in this case. The xreg argument will allow you to include additional covariates.

It should look something like this..

```
library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(y, order=c(1,0,0),xreg = x)
```